# Using Glide on Android doesn't reliably load image every time after clearing data/cache

Tags: android, android-glide

I have a simple activity with an imageView dropped in and I'm trying to wrap my head around Glide. The issue is that sporadically, the image doesn't load in the imageview.

Every now and then (1/20 tries it seems like), but it's pretty inconsistent, the image doesn't load at all and I'm stuck with the placeholder. Here's the code in the Activity onCreate()

```
Glide.with(ImageViewActivity.this.getApplicationContext())
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView));
```

Here is the layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.eghdk.glidedemo.ImageViewActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

I can guarantee that the network request happens because I have Charles Proxy open.

The steps I'm taking to get the image to redownload and display is, Apps > GlideDemoApp > Storage > Clear Data. This should clear the cache and display the image in the next onCreate. It works about 95% of the time, but in an area where I have a connection and I can check that I definitely get the image through Charles, I'm not really sure what else could be the issue and I can't have this happen in production.

Comment: Have you tried using activity context instead of applicationcontext. Ie Glide.with(this)?

Comment: Should that make a difference? I'll try it.

Comment: No difference. It only occurs from images served from my server and not other servers. Everything looks good though. Not sure why it still works "most" of the time and just does nothing other times. The request and response looks identical to when it works vs when it fails. Anyone have any ideas on how to start to debug this? Seems like glide doesn't play nice with the return headers in my opinion.

Comment: Maybe something to do with caching? (and cache control headers)

Comment: Can't modify my server easily right now. Any idea if it's possible to intercept the call and modify the headers? I know you can do it with OkHttp.

Comment: Has to be something with headers I suppose. I'm using Picasso now as a sanity check and it's working 100%. So I will try to work with my server to try to get it working with Glide. For now I'll use Picasso I guess.